# Poner header debajo de un div

Tags: html, css

Tengo una Cabecera y me gustaría ponerlo debajo del div de menús usando sólo CSS, sin tocar el HTML, es eso posible?

```
  <body>
    <header>Cabecera</header>
    <div class="menus">
      <nav class="menu-izquierdo">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
      </nav>
      <nav class="menu-derecho">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <main>
      <article>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis
        atque quia, rerum voluptates veniam quod culpa iusto vel, odio nulla
        enim amet? Quod consectetur a laudantium vitae architecto labore
        laborum.
      </article>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un header, es un div con nombre. Si quieres ponerlo en otro lado, puedes hacerlo.

Comment: No termino de entender tu duda @RoyalUp, ¿puedes ser mas claro por favor?

Comment: Pero como puedo ponerlo justo debajo del div de menús tal y como está declarado todo?

Comment: Copialo, y pegalo en la seccion que quieres.

Comment: @BetaM perdona si no he sido claro , mi idea(estoy practicando) es meter ese header en medio del div , el de menús y el main

Comment: @Excorpion , sí pero mi idea es no tocar el html , pensaba si se podía hacer en css o no

Comment: ahhh @RoyalUp por ahi debimos de empezar, eso no queda nada claro en la pregunta, ¿al respecto has tratado algo?

Comment: Sí , perdona , la idea es hacerlo con css , sin tocar el html @BetaM

Comment: Si, haciendo la altura que ocupe y el ancho 100%

Comment: Aunque no me termina de quedar clara la idea detrás de esto, puedes usar *flexbox* y *reacomodar* los elementos mediante [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

Comment: Estoy probando con order , pero no sale

Comment: Y colocaste los elementos dentro de un contenedor con display flex?, si no haces eso entonces nada relacionado a flexbox va a trabajar

Comment: El body que es lo que contiene a los elementos que tengo que ordenar , le puse el display:flex , claro

Answer (score 1):

si no quieres mover nada del HTML, una de las pocas opciones es forzando las posiciones de los elementos.
para usar otras cosas como un flexbox como te mencionan en los comentarios, tendrías que agruparlos en contenedores.

```css
 header, .menus, main  {
  position: absolute
 }
 header { 
  top: 250px;
 }
 .menus { 
  top: -20px;
 }
 main { 
  top: 280px;
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>Cabecera</header>
    <div class="menus">
      <nav class="menu-izquierdo">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
      </nav>
      <nav class="menu-derecho">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
        <div>Item</div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <main>
      <article>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis
        atque quia, rerum voluptates veniam quod culpa iusto vel, odio nulla
        enim amet? Quod consectetur a laudantium vitae architecto labore
        laborum.
      </article>
    </main>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probaste así:

```
<body>
<div class="div-nuevo">Div Nuevo</div>
<header>Cabecera</header>
<div class="menus">
  <nav class="menu-izquierdo">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
  </nav>
  <nav class="menu-derecho">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
  </nav>
</div>
<main>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis
    atque quia, rerum voluptates veniam quod culpa iusto vel, odio nulla
    enim amet? Quod consectetur a laudantium vitae architecto labore
    laborum.
  </article>
</main>
```

Esa es la forma que yo conozco. Tal vez te sirve. No es CSS, es HTML pero es la más sencilla a mi entender.